# Getting closest element with jQuery

Tags: jquery-selectors, jquery

I have this markup:

```
<div class="news-listItem">
     <p class="date">Date: 06.03.2012</p>
     <h2><a href="#">test aaaaa</a></h2>
     <div class="news-content">Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</div>
     <a href="#" class="read-more">Read more</a>
</div>
```

I want to get the read more button based on the div `class="news-content"`. My jQuery code looks like this:

```
$('.news-content').closest('a.read-more').on('click', function(){
// code here
});
```

But this is not working. I have multiple posts on a page so I can not do `$('a.read-more')`.

Comment: Just use .next() if it always going to be next item. $('.news-content').next().on('click', function(){...});

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.closest()` traverses up the DOM tree. What you need is `.next()`:

```
$('.news-content').next('a.read-more')
```

Answer (score 5):

The `closest`*<sup>[[API]](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)</sup>* method gets an ancestor. You need the `siblings`*<sup>[[API]](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)</sup>* method.

```
$('.news-content').siblings('a.read-more').on('click', function(){
// code here
});
```

Comment: While user zerkms suggested `.next()` works, I'd prefer the use of `.siblings()` as more general, looking in both ways. +

Comment: @kontur: it depends on the task. There is no reason in programming to do more work than it is required. "General" is not synonymous to "better"

Comment: Certainly. In real world use I sometimes found myself looking for errors because manipulating the DOM would cause the object not to be `.next()` or `.prev()` any more - personally, I find it more easy to think of which level of the DOM I am in, not necessairly, if to look ahead or back on that level. But you are absolutely right, it is merely a personal/situational preference, both answers are equally valid.

Comment: I would argue that `siblings` is slightly more future-proof than `next` with no added programming cost, because as long as the elements remain at the same DOM level, it works. `next` is more brittle. Execution cost may differ, but I bet it's similar or negligible. In the end, both `siblings` and `next` are sufficient solutions given the context, so the OP can decide which fits best.

Comment: @FishBasketGordo: "as long as the elements remain at the same DOM level" --- this is the key phrase. You should never try to implement "universal" solution as long as the real universality in fact is very limited by special cases.

Comment: @zerkms I never said it was a universal solution. I said it was a slightly better solution given the context in my opinion.

Comment: @FishBasketGordo: you (and me) don't know how markup can be changed there. And guessing-driven development never leads to good results ;-)

Comment: @zerkms But that's exactly my point. `next` requires that the markup will never change. The two elements *must* remain in the same position relative to each other. `siblings` provides a greater degree of freedom to change the markup without changing the script, at no additional programming cost (well, it costs 4-letters more). Furthermore, there's no guessing here: it's true that one element comes after the other as much as it's true that they are siblings.

Comment: @FishBasketGordo: what if html-guy decides to wrap that `<a>...</a>` tag with another `<div>`? It is quite common change and both solution would fail.

Comment: @zerkms Yes, both would fail in that case, but if another element were  inserted between the `<div>` and the `<a>` (another common change), `next` would fail and `siblings` would not. In my opinion, that makes it a better choice.

Comment: @FishBasketGordo: oh! That is what I missed. I always thought that `next()` would find any sibling that goes after the selected element... Then, yes, you're right, and +1

Comment: @zerkms You were thinking of `nextAll`. That would have made for a less compelling argument for `siblings`, certainly. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS selectors:

```
$('.news-content+a.read-more').on('click', function(){
    // code here
});
```

I think it's better, because modern browsers support the native search for the selector.